# writing output to a text file R

Tags: r, text, file-io

I have below code. It works fine.

1. But i want to write the text within square braces - ["gaugeid" :
   "gauge1234",] to a line in the file. How can I do that?
2. I also want to write the text within square braces to a line -
   ["abc" : 5,] where 5 in actual value of variable abc. How could I do
   that?

I am confused as my line starts with " and ends with '

```
abc=5
sink("output.txt")
cat("\n")
cat("abc : ")
#cat(""gaugeid" : "gauge1234",")
sink()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have naked double-quotes in an R string unless is surrounded by single quotes.

```
> cat('"gaugeid" : "gauge1234",')
"gaugeid" : "gauge1234",
```

Or you can escape the double quotes inside your original effort:

```
> cat("\"gaugeid\" : \"gauge1234\",")
"gaugeid" : "gauge1234",
```

For the second question is as simple as adding a comma and the variable name which will hten be evaluated before writing to the output device:

```
> cat("abc : ", abc)
abc :  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
abc=5
sink("output.txt")
cat("\n")
cat("abc : ")
cat(abc)
cat(",")
sink()
```

The first cat("abc") is adding the string abc, while the second cat(abc) is adding the variable abc to the output file.